# What is the integral analogue of the inequality $\sum_i |a_i||b_i| \le \sum_i |a_i| \sum_i |b_i|$?

Tags: integration, inequality, functional-inequalities

I thought the integral version of this equality is
$ \int_a^b |f(x)g(x)| dx \le (b-a)\cdot \int_{a}^b |f(x)|dx \cdot \int_{a}^b |g(x)|dx$ for real continuous function $f,g$ on $[a,b]$.

But I found that there is a counterexample of this inequality.

Is there a similar inequality with respect to integral corresponding to $\sum_i |a_i||b_i| \le (\sum_i |a_i|) (\sum_i |b_i|)$?

Comment: Why should the inequality with the sums hold?

Comment: Minkowski inequality?

Comment: Well, you could easily apply that inequality on the corresponding Riemann sums and then take the limit to get an integral version, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Your guess would be right if you required the same monotonicity of $|f|$ and $|g|$. See *Chebyshev's Inequality*.

Comment: @VIVID, thanks. The Chebyshev’s inequality is what I am looking for.

Comment: I don’t think that inequality is try, Minkowsi’s inequality involve conjugate powers ($\frac{1}{p} +\frac{1}{q}=1$.

Comment: @VIVID, but it still seems weird because the original summation inequality doesn’t require the monotoness of ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ while the functions $f,g$ satisfy the reverse monotone condition. Why is it?

Comment: @user29422 Maybe the inequality should also require this. I have not checked it.

Comment: @VIVID, No, the inequality doesn’t require monoton condition. It is easily checked! $\sum_i |a_i||b_i| \le (\sum_i |a_i|) (\sum_i |b_i|)$.